# create search option for local webpages by tagging a page

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

My actual question is how would I go about creating a autocomplete dropdown off tags that will refer to a particular page, like on this site.

*I already have a autocomlete dropdown and it looks in the db field for a word starting with
something% (wildcard),but that is just one word*

What if you would have like 5 tags, comma seperated like tag1, tag2, tag3, etc, in one field
that will refer to one particular page.
How would you start the query looking for tags starting with the letter F for example,  extract them and put them in the dropdownlist and also get the url from the url field at the same time ofcourse.

> and also by typing two or more tags,
>   the results should get more precise

These are just my own thoughts, I have not figured out what would be the best way to acomplish this.

**EDIT**
I used the information below to cook something up like this.
I still have to make a page with the search results, so this is by long not ready.

```
CREATE TABLE tag_targets (
  tag_target_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  tag_target_naam varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  tag_target_url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (tag_target_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  tag varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (tag_id),
  UNIQUE KEY tag (tag)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE target_tag (
  tag_target_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  tag_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_target_id) REFERENCES tag_targets(tag_target_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


$q = "SELECT t1.tag_target_url,t2.tag FROM tag_targets AS t1,tags AS t2, target_tag AS t3 WHERE t1.tag_target_id = t3.tag_target_id AND t2.tag_id = t3.tag_id AND tag LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10";
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: looking at your sql query, it will return targets that match any of the entered tags (OR), and not all of them (tag1 AND tag2)

Comment: I know, your syntax is better. I was just trying out, if I remembered how some off the syntax worked. Too bad, that subselects are not allowed. By the way, I did that before I saw that you edited your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably not have the tags in a single field for that page (comma separated) but a "tags" table:

```
tags:
ID | name
---------
 1 | tag1
 2 | tag2
 3 | tag3
 4 | tag4


page_tags:
page_id | tag_id
----------------
      1 | 2 
      1 | 3
      2 | 1
      3 | 4
      3 | 3
```

you can query for any tags in a simple way, and get any matching pages as well.

For example, if the user types "tag3" it would match page 1 and 3, but "tag2, tag3" (or "tag3, tag2" - the order is irrelevant) would only match page 1.

Example SQL query for the above:

```
SELECT 
    page_tags.page_id
FROM
    page_tags INNER JOIN tags
    ON page_tags.tag_id=tags.id
WHERE
    tags.name IN ('tag3', 'tag2') 
GROUP BY
    page_id HAVING count(page_tags.tag_id) = 2
```

Comment: thanks for the sql syntax--to get tag3 and tag2 in the sql from the taxtbox, I probably have to use some kind off split function, explode(), split(), am guessing?

Comment: probably - that will depend on how the data is used/transformed at the either the client-side (browser) or server - so there are multiple ways of achieving the same result

Comment: only your sql innerjoin should be "=tags.tag_id"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use jQuery for making autocomplete fields. It has a good interface for making them:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete